# Calling a Macro from Another Workbook with Varying Date

Tags: excel, vba

please could someone help with the following code (it is quite simple/basic):

- The code is essentially opening a workbook (which is rolled over daily) - this is a daily file which therefore has a new name daily varying by latest close of business date (i.e. workday - 1)
- It is then running (calling) a Macro within that workbook - the Macro name also varies daily by latest close of business date
- Copying data from two tabs (namely "IR Delta" and "XCCY Delta" below) after that Macro has run into the current workbook
- Closing and saving that workbook accordingly
- The code works fine for the current date, however, I need to copy and paste each file daily and roll the date over for each close of business date. Thus, the date at the end of the file name varies
- When I have tried to add "Format(Range("cobdate"), "yyyy mm dd")" to wherever in the file paths is needed, I get an error message that the 'Subscript is out of range'

How do I make the below dates variable accordingly? it works for the 'Workbooks.Open' line of code, but not for any of the ones after

Thanks in advance!

---

```
Sub GetSensData()

Dim rng As Range
Dim Mail_Date As String
Mail_Date = Range("cobdate")

'Open a workbook

'Open method requires full file path to be referenced.

Workbooks.Open "\\sirius.ants.ad.anplc.co.uk\Reporting\" & Format(Range("cobdate"), "yyyy") & "\" & Format(Range("cobdate"), "mm Mmmm") & "\Report " & Format(Range("cobdate"), "yyyy mm dd") & " (old vesion).xlsm"

'Run the Full Daily Process macro in Old Version to be copied into New Version

Application.Run "'Report " & Format(Range("cobdate"), "yyyy mm dd") & " (old vesion).xlsm'!fullDailyProcess"

'Message Box to say 'Done' when ran Macro

MsgBox ("Old Version Macro ran!")

'Copy the IR Delta sheet from Old Version into New Version

Workbooks("Report 2020 10 01 (old vesion).xlsm").Worksheets("IR Delta").Range("A1:AL9").Copy _
Workbooks("20201001_SNP_Rates_PNL MR.xlsm").Worksheets("IR Delta").Range("A1")

'Worksheets("IR Delta").Activate

'Copy the XCCY Delta sheet from Old Version into New Version

Workbooks("Report 2020 10 01 (old vesion).xlsm").Worksheets("XCCY Delta").Range("A1:AL7").Copy _
Workbooks("20201001_Report.xlsm").Worksheets("XCCY Delta").Range("A1")

Worksheets("XCCY Delta").Activate

'Save and close old version

Workbooks("Report 2020 10 01 (old vesion).xlsm").Close SaveChanges:=True

End Sub
```

Answer (score -1):

Once you open another Workbook, you no longer have access to the "cobdate" Name in the ActiveWorkbook, as the new Workbook is now on top (and your new workbook doesn't have a range called "cobdate"). That's why your code works to open the new workbook but not thereafter. You are almost there with your Mail_Date variable: set the old and new dates at the start before you open any other Workbooks.

```
Dim newDate as Date
Dim oldDate as Date
newDate = Range("cobdate").Value
oldDate = WorksheetFunction.WorkDay(newDate,-1)
```

Whenever you need the formatted date use Format(newDate, ...) or Format(oldDate,...") as appropriate.

Comment: Hi there, thanks for your help. I had changed it to the following, which seems to work. However, I want to make the second workbook dynamic as well, but am unsure how as when I 'dim' and 'set' the second workbook as something else it doesn't seem to work. Can you help with that please?

Comment: You only declare (Dim) a variable once. You can assign it (Set) as often as you like.